# How exclude specific cell into a array of array in BigQuery wihtout break my structure?

Tags: arrays, google-cloud-platform, struct, google-bigquery

I try to select in BigQuery all value of my final select (in the code below   "SELECT * from temp_ship as p" ) except the value **id** and the  **last_changed_at** of **t1_ship_line**  (i need these value for my join but after, i dont need to get them in my last select. I need to keep my structure of array too in the process.

I try to use except but without sucess, any idea ?

Line 1 what i had actually , and line 3 what i seek to obtain (i search to remove the 2 orange column in my final select , in normal table without array i wrote juste the column that i need but here i can't write aaa.bbb.cccc for example :/ )
[image]

Here my code

```
WITH
  t1_ship_line AS (
  SELECT
    id, last_changed_at, line_number as line_num, article_id as product_id, quantity as product_qty, order_item_id
  FROM
    `table1` ),
  temp_ship AS (
  SELECT
    CAST(o_id AS INT64) AS id,
    CAST(a.last_changed_at AS TIMESTAMP) AS last_changed_at,
    ARRAY_AGG( STRUCT (id AS id,
        comment AS comment,
        carrier_id AS carrier_code,
        carrier_label AS carrier_label,
        tracking AS tracking_code,
        b AS line )) AS shipment,
  FROM
    `table2` a
  LEFT JOIN t1_ship_line b
  ON a.o_id = b.id
  and a.last_changed_at = b.last_changed_at
  GROUP BY
    o_id,
    last_changed_at )

SELECT * from temp_ship as p
```

Here a sample of data of the 2 tables :

`table1`

id,last_changed_at,line_num,product_id,quantity ,order_item_id

3000000000,2021-07-06 12:07:00 UTC,1,999999,6.0,0

3000000001,2021-07-06 12:07:00 UTC,1,999998,6.0,0

`table2`

id,o_id,last_changed_at,comment,carrier_id,carrier_label,tracking

100,3000000000,2021-07-06 12:07:00 UTC,COMMENT,nameofcarrierid,labelofcarrier,LOC

100,3000000001,2021-07-06 12:07:00 UTC,COMMENT,nameofcarrierid,labelofcarrier,LOC

Thanks in advance for your help ;)

Comment: provide sample of input data and expected output so we can help you

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant i provide some sample of the 2 tables,  if it's not enough, don't hesitate to reply, thanks for your help

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your case and I don't understand why you perform an ARRAY_AGG. Can you provide more context and a real input dataset (with shipment in it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some energy spend, here the tricks is to do a array_agg(struct ()) + over partition by in **t1_ship_line**  like below :

```
t1_ship_line AS (
  SELECT
    id, last_changed_at, line_number as line_num, article_id as product_id, quantity as product_qty, order_item_id,
    array_agg(struct(line_number as line_num , article_id as product_id, cast(quantity as NUMERIC) as product_qty, cast(order_item_id as INT64) as order_item_id )) over (partition by orders_shipment_id,last_changed_at) as shipment
  FROM
    `table1` 
),
temp_shipment as (
SELECT
    CAST(orders_id AS INT64) AS id,
    CAST(a.last_changed_at AS TIMESTAMP) AS last_changed_at,
    ARRAY_AGG( STRUCT (id AS id,
        comment AS comment,
        carrier_id AS carrier_code,
        carrier_label AS carrier_label,
        tracking AS tracking_code,
        b.shipment as line )) as shipment
  FROM
    `table2` a
  LEFT JOIN t1_ship_line b
  ON a.orders_id = b.orders_shipment_id
  and a.last_changed_at = b.last_changed_at
  GROUP BY
    orders_id,
    last_changed_at
) select * from temp_shipment
```